# Replace LINQ method with inline LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have the code that is working fine.

```
 RequsitionView ConvertMethod(Models.Requisition  input)
 {
    return new RequsitionView(input);
 }

  .... 

model.Requisitions = AppModel.Requisitions.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId).Select(ConvertMethod).ToList();
```

But I would like to simplify it and replace `ConvertMethod` with inline LINQ expression.

I cannot figure out how to do it.

Any clue?

P.S. I have tried some of solutions but no joy.

I.e.

```
model.Requisitions = AppModel.Requisitions
                             .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
                             .Select(input => new RequsitionView(input))
                             .ToList();
```

By the way `RequsitionView` class is

```
public sealed class RequsitionView
    {

        public RequsitionView()
        {

        }

        public RequsitionView(Requisition requisition)
        {
            UID = requisition.UID;
            Id = requisition.Id;
            ExpectedStartTime = requisition.ExpectedStartTime;
            ExpectedEndingTime = requisition.ExpectedEndingTime;
            RealEndingTime = requisition.RealEndingTime;
            ClientId = requisition.ClientId;
            ClientType = requisition.ClientType;
            PatientId = requisition.PatientId;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
model.Requisitions = AppModel.Requisitions
                             .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
                             .Select(input => new RequsitionView(input))
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: Well... Whe I try it I am facing that error Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Does the `RequsitionView` class have a publicly-settable property? If so, you could use initializer syntax: `.Select(input => new RequsitionView { Input = input })`

Comment: @James: Yes, I assumed it already has that. You'd still need some way of assigning the `input` value.

Comment: @Douglas Thanks for the input! Pls take a look at my updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
model.Requisitions = AppModel.Requisitions
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
    .Select(x => new RequsitionView(x))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Select` method is a projection, therefore all you need to do is project each item as a new `RequisitionView` i.e.

```
var views = AppModel.Requisitions
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
    .Select(x => new RequisitionView(x))
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
model.Requisitions = AppModel.Requisitions.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId).Select(o=>new RequsitionView(o) ).ToList();
```